# How to open popup with javascript without web browser blocking popup on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am trying to load a popup window on page load with javascript. But when I try to do so with code below the web browser always blocks the popup window. How can i do it in a way that the popup opens properly without conflict with the browser.

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.google.in" target="_blank" style="display:none;" id="pcrentinglink"></a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var times_loaded_counter = localStorage.getItem('page_loaded_times');
  if (times_loaded_counter == "") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      localStorage.setItem('page_loaded_times', times_loaded_counter + 1);
      var link = document.getElementById("pcrentinglink").href;
      //alert(link);
      //window.open(link, '_blank');
      $("#pcrentinglink")[0].click();
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Because people used it ages ago to show ads so guess what, you can not do it

Comment: If users don't want to allow popups then they must be able to disable them. No way to work around that. Instead look for an alternative, like an `<iframe>` to do something similar.

Comment: @epascarello i have seen in some site where on page click new tab opens. Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: Yes you can open up a new tab/window with a click event since the user initiated that action.

Comment: @epascarello i just changed to code to trigger click event still its getting blocked by the browser.